# My CSS file is in 1 line

Tags: css

My whole css file is in one line.

Can we convert that css file in to many lines?

Any tricks??

```
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary{display:block}audio,canvas,video{display:inline-block}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}[hidden],template{display:none}html{font-family:sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}a{background:transparent}a:focus{outline:thin dotted}a:active,a:hover{outline:0}h1{margin:.67em 0;font-size:2em}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}b,strong{font-weight:bold}dfn{font-style:italic}hr{height:0;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}mark{color:#000;background:#ff0}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,serif;font-size:1em}pre{white-space:pre-wrap}q{quotes:"\201C" "\201D" "\2018" "\2019"}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{position:relative;font-size:75%;line-height:0;vertical-align:baseline}sup{top:-0.5em}sub{bottom:-0.25em}img{border:0}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}figure{margin:0}fieldset{padding:.35em .625em .75em;margin:0 2px;border:1px solid #c0c0c0}legend{padding:0;border:0}button,input,select,textarea{margin:0;font-family:inherit;font-size:100%}button,input{line-height:normal}button,select{text-transform:none}button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{cursor:pointer;-webkit-appearance:button}button[disabled],html input[disabled]{cursor:default}input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}input[type="search"]{-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;-webkit-appearance:textfield}input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{padding:0;border:0}textarea{overflow:auto;vertical-align:top}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}@media print{*{color:#000!important;text-shadow:none!important;background:transparent!important;box-shadow:none!important}a,a:visited{text-decoration:underline}a[href]:after{content:" (" attr(href) ")"}abbr[title]:after{content:" (" attr(title) ")"}a[href^="javascript:"]:after,a[href^="#"]:after{content:""}pre,blockquote{border:1px solid #999;page-break-inside:avoid}thead{display:table-header-group}tr,img{page-break-inside:avoid}img{max-width:100%!important}@page{margin:2cm .5cm}p,h2,h3{orphans:3;widows:3}h2,h3{page-break-after:avoid}select{background:#fff!important}.navbar{display:none}.table td,.table th{background-color:#fff!important}.btn>.caret,.dropup>.btn>.caret{border-top-color:#000!important}.label{border:1px solid #000}.table{border-collapse:collapse!important}.table-bordered th,.table-bordered td{border:1px solid #ddd!important}}*,*:before,*:after{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}html{font-size:62.5%;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)}body{font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:1.428571429;color:#333;background-color:#fff}input,button,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;line-height:inherit}a{color:#428bca;text-decoration:none}a:hover,a:focus{color:#2a6496;text-decoration:underline}a:focus{outline:thin dotted;outline:5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;outline-offset:-2px}img{vertical-align:middle}.img-responsive{display:block;height:auto;max-width:100%}.img-rounded{border-radius:6px}.img-thumbnail{display:inline-block;height:auto;max-width:100%;padding:4px;line-height:1.428571429;background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #ddd;border-radius:4px;-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;transition:all .2s ease-in-out}.img-circle{border-radius:50%}hr{margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;border:0;border-top:1px solid #eee}.sr-only{position:absolute;width:1px;height:1px;padding:0;margin:-1px;overflow:hidden;clip:rect(0,0,0,0);border:0}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,.h1,.h2,.h3,.h4,.h5,.h6{font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:500;line-height:1.1;color:inherit}h1 small,h2 small,h3 small,h4 small,h5 small,h6 small,.h1 small,.h2 small,.h3 small,.h4 small,.h5 small,.h6 small,h1 .small,h2 .small,h3 .small,h4 .small,h5 .small,h6 .small,.h1 .small,.h2 .small,.h3 .small,.h4 .small,.h5 .small,.h6 .small{font-weight:normal;line-height:1;color:#999}h1,h2,h3{margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:10px}h1 small,h2 small,h3 small,h1 .small,h2 .small,h3 .small{font-size:65%}h4,h5,h6{margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px}h4 small,h5 small,h6 small,h4 .small,h5 .small,h6 .small{font-size:75%}h1,.h1{font-size:36px}h2,.h2{font-size:30px}h3,.h3{font-size:24px}h4,.h4{font-size:18px}h5,.h5{font-size:14px}h6,.h6{font-size:12px}p{margin:0 0 10px}.lead{margin-bottom:20px;font-size:16px;font-weight:200;line-height:1.4}@media(min-width:768px){.lead{font-size:21px}}small,.small{font-size:85%}cite{font-style:normal}.text-muted{color:#999}.text-primary{color:#428bca}.text-primary:hover{color:#3071a9}.text-warning{color:#8a6d3b}.text-warning:hover{color:#66512c}.text-danger{color:#a94442}.text-danger:hover{color:#843534}.text-success{color:#3c763d}.text-success:hover{color:#2b542c}.text-info{color:#31708f}.text-info:hover{color:#245269}.text-left{text-align:left}.text-right{text-align:right}.text-center{text-align:center}.page-header{padding-bottom:9px;margin:40px 0 20px;border-bottom:1px solid #eee}ul,ol{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:10px}ul ul,ol ul,ul ol,ol ol{margin-bottom:0}.list-unstyled{padding-left:0;list-style:none}.list-inline{padding-left:0;list-style:none}.list-inline>li{display:inline-block;padding-right:5px;padding-left:5px}.list-inline>li:first-child{padding-left:0}dl{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:20px}dt,dd{line-height:1.428571429}dt{font-weight:bold}dd{margin-left:0}@media(min-width:768px){.dl-horizontal dt{float:left;width:160px;overflow:hidden;clear:left;text-align:right;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap}.dl-horizontal dd{margin-left:180px}.dl-horizontal dd:before,.dl-horizontal dd:after{display:table;content:" "}.dl-horizontal dd:after{clear:both}.dl-horizontal dd:before,.dl-horizontal dd:after{display:table;content:" "}.dl-horizontal dd:after{clear:both}}abbr[title],abbr[data-original-title]{cursor:help;border-bottom:1px dotted #999}.initialism{font-size:90%;text-transform:uppercase}blockquote{padding:10px 20px;margin:0 0 20px;border-left:5px solid #eee}blockquote p{font-size:17.5px;font-weight:300;line-height:1.25}blockquote p:last-child{margin-bottom:0}blockquote small,blockquote .small{display:block;line-height:1.428571429;color:#999}blockquote small:before,blockquote .small:before{content:'\2014 \00A0'}blockquote.pull-right{padding-right:15px;padding-left:0;border-right:5px solid #eee;border-left:0}blockquote.pull-right p,blockquote.pull-right small,blockquote.pull-right .small{text-align:right}blockquote.pull-right small:before,blockquote.pull-right .small:before{content:''}blockquote.pull-right small:after,blockquote.pull-right .small:after{content:'\00A0 \2014'}blockquote:before,blockquote:after{content:""}address{margin-bottom:20px;font-style:normal;line-height:1.428571429}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Courier New",monospace}code{padding:2px 4px;font-size:90%;color:#c7254e;white-space:nowrap;background-color:#f9f2f4;border-radius:4px}pre{display:block;padding:9.5px;margin:0 0 10px;font-size:13px;line-height:1.428571429;color:#333;word-break:break-all;word-wrap:break-word;background-color:#f5f5f5;border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:4px}pre code{padding:0;font-size:inherit;color:inherit;white-space:pre-wrap;background-color:transparent;border-radius:0}.pre-scrollable{max-height:340px;overflow-y:scroll}.container{padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto}.container:before,.container:after{display:table;content:" "}.container:after{clear:both}.container:before,.container:after{display:table;content:" "}.container:after{clear:both}@media(min-width:768px){.container{width:750px}}@media(min-width:992px){.container{width:970px}}@media(min-width:1200px){.container{width:1170px}}.row{margin-right:-15px;margin-left:-15px}.row:before,.row:after{display:table;content:" "}.row:after{clear:both}.row:before,.row:after{display:table;content:" "}.row:after{clear:both}.col-xs-1,.col-sm-1,.col-md-1,.col-lg-1,.col-xs-2,.col-sm-2,.col-md-2,.col-lg-2,.col-xs-3,.col-sm-3,.col-md-3,.col-lg-3,.col-xs-4,.col-sm-4,.col-md-4,.col-lg-4,.col-xs-5,.col-sm-5,.col-md-5,.col-lg-5,.col-xs-6,.col-sm-6,.col-md-6,.col-lg-6,.col-xs-7,.col-sm-7,.col-md-7,.col-lg-7,.col-xs-8,.col-sm-8,.col-md-8,.col-lg-8,.col-xs-9,.col-sm-9,.col-md-9,.col-lg-9,.col-xs-10,.col-sm-10,.col-md-10,.col-lg-10,.col-xs-11,.col-sm-11,.col-md-11,.col-lg-11,.col-xs-12,.col-sm-12,.col-md-12,.col-lg-12{position:relative;min-height:1px;padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px}.col-xs-1,.col-xs-2,.col-xs-3,.col-xs-4,.col-xs-5,.col-xs-6,.col-xs-7,.col-xs-8,.col-xs-9,.col-xs-10,.col-xs-11,.col-xs-12{float:left}.col-xs-12{width:100%}.col-xs-11{width:91.66666666666666%}.col-xs-10{width:83.33333333333334%}.col-xs-9{width:75%}.col-xs-8{width:66.66666666666666%}.col-xs-7{width:58.333333333333336%}.col-xs-6{width:50%}.col-xs-5{width:41.66666666666667%}.col-xs-4{width:33.33333333333333%}.col-xs-3{width:25%}.col-xs-2{width:16.666666666666664%}.col-xs-1{width:8.333333333333332%}.col-xs-pull-12{right:100%}.col-xs-pull-11{right:91.66666666666666%}.col-xs-pull-10{right:83.33333333333334%}.col-xs-pull-9{right:75%}.col-xs-pull-8{right:66.66666666666666%}.col-xs-pull-7{right:58.333333333333336%}.col-xs-pull-6{right:50%}.col-xs-pull-5{right:41.66666666666667%}.col-xs-pull-4{right:33.33333333333333%}.col-xs-pull-3{right:25%}.col-xs-pull-2{right:16.666666666666664%}.col-xs-pull-1{right:8.333333333333332%}.col-xs-pull-0{right:0}.col-xs-push-12{left:100%}.col-xs-push-11{left:91.66666666666666%}.col-xs-push-10{left:83.33333333333334%}.col-xs-push-9{left:75%}.col-xs-push-8{left:66.66666666666666%}.col-xs-push-7{left:58.333333333333336%}.col-xs-push-6{left:50%}.col-xs-push-5{left:41.66666666666667%}.col-xs-push-4{left:33.33333333333333%}.col-xs-push-3{left:25%}.col-xs-push-2{left:16.666666666666664%}.col-xs-push-1{left:8.333333333333332%}.col-xs-push-0{left:0}.col-xs-offset-12{margin-left:100%}.col-xs-offset-11{margin-left:91.66666666666666%}.col-xs-offset-10{margin-left:83.33333333333334%}.col-xs-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-xs-offset-8{margin-left:66.66666666666666%}.col-xs-offset-7{margin-left:58.333333333333336%}.col-xs-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-xs-offset-5{margin-left:41.66666666666667%}.col-xs-offset-4{margin-left:33.33333333333333%}.col-xs-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-xs-offset-2{margin-left:16.666666666666664%}.col-xs-offset-1{margin-left:8.333333333333332%}.col-xs-offset-0{margin-left:0}@media(min-width:768px){.col-sm-1,.col-sm-2,.col-sm-3,.col-sm-4,.col-sm-5,.col-sm-6,.col-sm-7,.col-sm-8,.col-sm-9,.col-sm-10,.col-sm-11,.col-sm-12{float:left}.col-sm-12{width:100%}.col-sm-11{width:91.66666666666666%}.col-sm-10{width:83.33333333333334%}.col-sm-9{width:75%}.col-sm-8{width:66.66666666666666%}.col-sm-7{width:58.333333333333336%}.col-sm-6{width:50%}.col-sm-5{width:41.66666666666667%}.col-sm-4{width:33.33333333333333%}.col-sm-3{width:25%}.col-sm-2{width:16.666666666666664%}.col-sm-1{width:8.333333333333332%}.col-sm-pull-12{right:100%}.col-sm-pull-11{right:91.66666666666666%}.col-sm-pull-10{right:83.33333333333334%}.col-sm-pull-9{right:75%}.col-sm-pull-8{right:66.66666666666666%}.col-sm-pull-7{right:58.333333333333336%}.col-sm-pull-6{right:50%}.col-sm-pull-5{right:41.66666666666667%}.col-sm-pull-4{right:33.33333333333333%}.col-sm-pull-3{right:25%}.col-sm-pull-2{right:16.666666666666664%}.col-sm-pull-1{right:8.333333333333332%}.col-sm-pull-0{right:0}.col-sm-push-12{left:100%}.col-sm-push-11{left:91.66666666666666%}.col-sm-push-10{left:83.33333333333334%}.col-sm-push-9{left:75%}.col-sm-push-8{left:66.66666666666666%}.col-sm-push-7{left:58.333333333333336%}.col-sm-push-6{left:50%}.col-sm-push-5{left:41.66666666666667%}.col-sm-push-4{left:33.33333333333333%}.col-sm-push-3{left:25%}.col-sm-push-2{left:16.666666666666664%}.col-sm-push-1{left:8.333333333333332%}.col-sm-push-0{left:0}.col-sm-offset-12{margin-left:100%}.col-sm-offset-11{margin-left:91.66666666666666%}.col-sm-offset-10{margin-left:83.33333333333334%}.col-sm-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-sm-offset-8{margin-left:66.66666666666666%}.col-sm-offset-7{margin-left:58.333333333333336%}.col-sm-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-sm-offset-5{margin-left:41.66666666666667%}.col-sm-offset-4{margin-left:33.33333333333333%}.col-sm-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-sm-offset-2{margin-left:16.666666666666664%}.col-sm-offset-1{margin-left:8.333333333333332%}.col-sm-offset-0{margin-left:0}}@media(min-width:992px){.col-md-1,.col-md-2,.col-md-3,.col-md-4,.col-md-5,.col-md-6,.col-md-7,.col-md-8,.col-md-9,.col-md-10,.col-md-11,.col-md-12{float:left}.col-md-12{width:100%}.col-md-11{width:91.66666666666666%}.col-md-10{width:83.33333333333334%}.col-md-9{width:75%}.col-md-8{width:66.66666666666666%}.col-md-7{width:58.333333333333336%}.col-md-6{width:50%}.col-md-5{width:41.66666666666667%}.col-md-4{width:33.33333333333333%}.col-md-3{width:25%}.col-md-2{width:16.666666666666664%}.col-md-1{width:8.333333333333332%}.col-md-pull-12{right:100%}.col-md-pull-11{right:91.66666666666666%}.col-md-pull-10{right:83.33333333333334%}.col-md-pull-9{right:75%}.col-md-pull-8{right:66.66666666666666%}.col-md-pull-7{right:58.333333333333336%}.col-md-pull-6{right:50%}.col-md-pull-5{right:41.66666666666667%}.col-md-pull-4{right:33.33333333333333%}.col-md-pull-3{right:25%}.col-md-pull-2{right:16.666666666666664%}.col-md-pull-1{right:8.333333333333332%}.col-md-pull-0{right:0}.col-md-push-12{left:100%}.col-md-push-11{left:91.66666666666666%}.col-md-push-10{left:83.33333333333334%}.col-md-push-9{left:75%}.col-md-push-8{left:66.66666666666666%}.col-md-push-7{left:58.333333333333336%}.col-md-push-6{left:50%}.col-md-push-5{left:41.66666666666667%}.col-md-push-4{left:33.33333333333333%}.col-md-push-3{left:25%}.col-md-push-2{left:16.666666666666664%}.col-md-push-1{left:8.333333333333332%}.col-md-push-0{left:0}.col-md-offset-12{margin-left:100%}.col-md-offset-11{margin-left:91.66666666666666%}.col-md-offset-10{margin-left:83.33333333333334%}.col-md-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-md-offset-8{margin-left:66.66666666666666%}.col-md-offset-7{margin-left:58.333333333333336%}.col-md-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-md-offset-5{margin-left:41.66666666666667%}.col-md-offset-4{margin-left:33.33333333333333%}.col-md-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-md-offset-2{margin-left:16.666666666666664%}.col-md-offset-1{margin-left:8.333333333333332%}.col-md-offset-0{margin-left:0}}@media(min-width:1200px){.col-lg-1,.col-lg-2,.col-lg-3,.col-lg-4,.col-lg-5,.col-lg-6,.col-lg-7,.col-lg-8,.col-lg-9,.col-lg-10,.col-lg-11,.col-lg-12{float:left}.col-lg-12{width:100%}.col-lg-11{width:91.66666666666666%}.col-lg-10{width:83.33333333333334%}.col-lg-9{width:75%}.col-lg-8{width:66.66666666666666%}.col-lg-7{width:58.333333333333336%}.col-lg-6{width:50%}.col-lg-5{width:41.66666666666667%}.col-lg-4{width:33.33333333333333%}.col-lg-3{width:25%}.col-lg-2{width:16.666666666666664%}.col-lg-1{width:8.333333333333332%}.col-lg-pull-12{right:100%}.col-lg-pull-11{right:91.66666666666666%}.col-lg-pull-10{right:83.33333333333334%}.col-lg-pull-9{right:75%}.col-lg-pull-8{right:66.66666666666666%}.col-lg-pull-7{right:58.333333333333336%}.col-lg-pull-6{right:50%}.col-lg-pull-5{right:41.66666666666667%}.col-lg-pull-4{right:33.33333333333333%}.col-lg-pull-3{right:25%}.col-lg-pull-2{right:16.666666666666664%}.col-lg-pull-1{right:8.333333333333332%}.col-lg-pull-0{right:0}.col-lg-push-12{left:100%}.col-lg-push-11{left:91.66666666666666%}.col-lg-push-10{left:83.33333333333334%}.col-lg-push-9{left:75%}.col-lg-push-8{left:66.66666666666666%}.col-lg-push-7{left:58.333333333333336%}.col-lg-push-6{left:50%}.col-lg-push-5{left:41.66666666666667%}.col-lg-push-4{left:33.33333333333333%}.col-lg-push-3{left:25%}.col-lg-push-2{left:16.666666666666664%}.col-lg-push-1{left:8.333333333333332%}.col-lg-push-0{left:0}.col-lg-offset-12{margin-left:100%}.col-lg-offset-11{margin-left:91.66666666666666%}.col-lg-offset-10{margin-left:83.33333333333334%}.col-lg-offset-9{margin-left:75%}.col-lg-offset-8{margin-left:66.66666666666666%}.col-lg-offset-7{margin-left:58.333333333333336%}.col-lg-offset-6{margin-left:50%}.col-lg-offset-5{margin-left:41.66666666666667%}.col-lg-offset-4{margin-left:33.33333333333333%}.col-lg-offset-3{margin-left:25%}.col-lg-offset-2{margin-left:16.666666666666664%}.col-lg-offset-1{margin-left:8.333333333333332%}.col-lg-offset-0{margin-left:0}}table{max-width:100%;background-color:transparent}th{text-align:left}.table{width:100%;margin-bottom:20px}.table>thead>tr>th,.table>tbody>tr>th,.table>tfoot>tr>th,.table>thead>tr>td,.table>tbody>tr>td,.table>tfoot>tr>td{padding:8px;line-height:1.428571429;vertical-align:top;border-top:1px solid #ddd}.table>thead>tr>th{vertical-align:bottom;border-bottom:2px solid #ddd}.table>caption+thead>tr:first-child>th,.table>colgroup+thead>tr:first-child>th,.table>thead:first-child>tr:first-child>th,.table>caption+thead>tr:first-child>td,.table>colgroup+thead>tr:first-child>td,.table>thead:first-child>tr:first-child>td{border-top:0}.table>tbody+tbody{border-top:2px solid #ddd}.table .table{background-color:#fff}.table-condensed>thead>tr>th,.table-condensed>tbody>tr>th,.table-condensed>tfoot>tr>th,.table-condensed>thead>tr>td,.table-condensed>tbody>tr>td,.table-condensed>tfoot>tr>td{padding:5px}.table-bordered{border:1px solid #ddd}.table-bordered>thead>tr>th,.table-bordered>tbody>tr>th,.table-bordered>tfoot>tr>th,.table-bordered>thead>tr>td,.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td,.table-bordered>tfoot>tr>td{border:1px solid #ddd}.table-bordered>thead>tr>th,.table-bordered>thead>tr>td{border-bottom-width:2px}.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td,.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th{background-color:#f9f9f9}.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover>td,.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover>th{background-color:#f5f5f5}table col[class*="col-"]{position:static;display:table-column;float:none}table td[class*="col-"],table th[class*="col-"]{display:table-cell;float:none}.table>thead>tr>.active,.table>tbody>tr>.active,.table>tfoot>tr>.active,.table>thead>.active>td,.table>tbody>.active>td,.table>tfoot>.active>td,.table>thead>.active>th,.table>tbody>.active>th,.table>tfoot>.active>th{background-color:#f5f5f5}.table-hover>tbody>tr>.active:hover,.table-hover>tbody>.active:hover>td,.table-hover>tbody>.active:hover>th{background-color:#e8e8e8}.table>thead>tr>.success,.table>tbody>tr>.success,.table>tfoot>tr>.success,.table>thead>.success>td,.table>tbody>.success>td,.table>tfoot>.success>td,.table>thead>.success>th,.table>tbody>.success>th,.table>tfoot>.success>th{background-color:#dff0d8}.table-hover>tbody>tr>.success:hover,.table-hover>tbody>.success:hover>td,.table-hover>tbody>.success:hover>th{background-color:#d0e9c6}.table>thead>tr>.danger,.table>tbody>tr>.danger,.table>tfoot>tr>.danger,.table>thead>.danger>td,.table>tbody>.danger>td,.table>tfoot>.danger>td,.table>thead>.danger>th,.table>tbody>.danger>th,.table>tfoot>.danger>th{background-color:#f2dede}.table-hover>tbody>tr>.danger:hover,.table-hover>tbody>.danger:hover>td,.table-hover>tbody>.danger:hover>th{background-color:#ebcccc}.table>thead>tr>.warning,.table>tbody>tr>.warning,.table>tfoot>tr>.warning,.table>thead>.warning>td,.table>tbody>.warning>td,.table>tfoot>.warning>td,.table>thead>.warning>th,.table>tbody>.warning>th,.table>tfoot>.warning>th{background-color:#fcf8e3}.table-hover>tbody>tr>.warning:hover,.table-hover>tbody>.warning:hover>td,.table-hover>tbody>.warning:hover>th{background-color:#faf2cc}@media(max-width:767px){.table-responsive{width:100%;margin-bottom:15px;overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:hidden;border:1px solid #ddd;-ms-overflow-style:-ms-autohiding-scrollbar;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch}.table-responsive>.table{margin-bottom:0}.table-responsive>.table>thead>tr>th,.table-responsive>.table>tbody>tr>th,.table-responsive>.table>tfoot>tr>th,.table-responsive>.table>thead>tr>td,.table-responsive>.table>tbody>tr>td,.table-responsive>.table>tfoot>tr>td{white-space:nowrap}.table-responsive>.table-bordered{border:0}.table-responsive>.table-bordered>thead>tr>th:first-child,.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tbody>tr>th:first-child,.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tfoot>tr>th:first-child,.table-responsive>.table-bordered>thead>tr>td:first-child,.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td:first-child,.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tfoot>tr>td:first-child{border-left:0}.table-responsive>.table-bordered>thead>tr>th:last-child,.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tbody>tr>th:last-child,.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tfoot>tr>th:last-child,.table-responsive>.table-bordered>thead>tr>td:last-child,.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td:last-child,.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tfoot>tr>td:last-child{border-right:0}.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tbody>tr:last-child>th,.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tfoot>tr:last-child>th,.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tbody>tr:last-child>td,.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tfoot>tr:last-child>td{border-bottom:0}}fieldset{padding:0;margin:0;border:0}legend{display:block;width:100%;padding:0;margin-bottom:20px;font-size:21px;line-height:inherit;color:#333;border:0;border-bottom:1px solid #e5e5e5}label{display:inline-block;margin-bottom:5px;font-weight:bold}input[type="search"]{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}input[type="radio"],input[type="checkbox"]{margin:4px 0 0;margin-top:1px \9;line-height:normal}input[type="file"]{display:block}select[multiple],select[size]{height:auto}select optgroup{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-style:inherit}input[type="file"]:focus,input[type="radio"]:focus,input[type="checkbox"]:focus{outline:thin dotted;outline:5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;outline-offset:-2px}input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button{height:auto}output{display:block;padding-top:7px;font-size:14px;line-height:1.428571429;color:#555;vertical-align:middle}.form-control{display:block;width:100%;height:34px;padding:6px 12px;font-size:14px;line-height:1.428571429;color:#555;vertical-align:middle;background-color:#fff;background-image:none;border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:4px;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);-webkit-transition:border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;transition:border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s}.form-control:focus{border-color:#66afe9;outline:0;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,0.6);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,0.6)}.form-control:-moz-placeholder{color:#999}.form-control::-moz-placeholder{color:#999;opacity:1}.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder{color:#999}.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:#999}.form-control[disabled],.form-control[readonly],fieldset[disabled] .form-control{cursor:not-allowed;background-color:#eee}textarea.form-control{height:auto}.form-group{margin-bottom:15px}.radio,.checkbox{display:block;min-height:20px;padding-left:20px;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;vertical-align:middle}.radio label,.checkbox label{display:inline;margin-bottom:0;font-weight:normal;cursor:pointer}.radio input[type="radio"],.radio-inline input[type="radio"],.checkbox input[type="checkbox"],.checkbox-inline input[type="checkbox"]{float:left;margin-left:-20px}.radio+.radio,.checkbox+.checkbox{margin-top:-5px}.radio-inline,.checkbox-inline{display:inline-block;padding-left:20px;margin-bottom:0;font-weight:normal;vertical-align:middle;cursor:pointer}.radio-inline+.radio-inline,.checkbox-inline+.checkbox-inline{margin-top:0;margin-left:10px}input[type="radio"][disabled],input[type="checkbox"][disabled],.radio[disabled],.radio-inline[disabled],.checkbox[disabled],.checkbox-inline[disabled],fieldset[disabled] input[type="radio"],fieldset[disabled] input[type="checkbox"],fieldset[disabled] .radio,fieldset[disabled] .radio-inline,fieldset[disabled] .checkbox,fieldset[disabled] .checkbox-inline{cursor:not-allowed}.input-sm{height:30px;padding:5px 10px;font-size:12px;line-height:1.5;border-radius:3px}select.input-sm{height:30px;line-height:30px}textarea.input-sm{height:auto}.input-lg{height:46px;padding:10px 16px;font-size:18px;line-height:1.33;border-radius:6px}select.input-lg{height:46px;line-height:46px}textarea.input-lg{height:auto}.has-warning .help-block,.has-warning .control-label,.has-warning .radio,.has-warning .checkbox,.has-warning .radio-inline,.has-warning .checkbox-inline{color:#8a6d3b}.has-warning .form-control{border-color:#8a6d3b;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075)}.has-warning .form-control:focus{border-color:#66512c;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 6px #c0a16b;box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 6px #c0a16b}.has-warning .input-group-addon{color:#8a6d3b;background-color:#fcf8e3;border-color:#8a6d3b}.has-error .help-block,.has-error .control-label,.has-error .radio,.has-error .checkbox,.has-error .radio-inline,.has-error .checkbox-inline{color:#a94442}.has-error .form-control{border-color:#a94442;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075)}.has-error .form-control:focus{border-color:#843534;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 6px #ce8483;box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 6px #ce8483}.has-error .input-group-addon{color:#a94442;background-color:#f2dede;border-color:#a94442}.has-success .help-block,.has-success .control-label,.has-success .radio,.has-success .checkbox,.has-success .radio-inline,.has-success .checkbox-inline{color:#3c763d}.has-success .form-control{border-color:#3c763d;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075)}.has-success .form-control:focus{border-color:#2b542c;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 6px #67b168;box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 6px #67b168}.has-success .input-group-addon{color:#3c763d;background-color:#dff0d8;border-color:#3c763d}.form-control-static{margin-bottom:0}.help-block{display:block;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:10px;color:#737373}@media(min-width:768px){.form-inline .form-group{display:inline-block;margin-bottom:0;vertical-align:middle}.form-inline .form-control{display:inline-block}.form-inline select.form-control{width:auto}.form-inline .radio,.form-inline .checkbox{display:inline-block;padding-left:0;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0}.form-inline .radio input[type="radio"],.form-inline .checkbox input[type="checkbox"]{float:none;margin-left:0}}.form-horizontal .control-label,.form-horizontal .radio,.form-horizontal .checkbox,.form-horizontal .radio-inline,.form-horizontal .checkbox-inline{padding-top:7px;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0}.form-horizontal .radio,.form-horizontal .checkbox{min-height:27px}.form-horizontal .form-group{margin-right:-15px;margin-left:-15px}.form-horizontal .form-group:before,.form-horizontal .form-group:after{display:table;content:" "}.form-horizontal .form-group:after{clear:both}.form-horizontal .form-group:before,.form-horizontal .form-group:after{display:table;content:" "}.form-horizontal .form-group:after{clear:both}.form-horizontal .form-control-static{padding-top:7px}@media(min-width:768px){.form-horizontal .control-label{text-align:right}}.btn{display:inline-block;padding:6px 12px;margin-bottom:0;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;line-height:1.428571429;text-align:center;white-space:nowrap;vertical-align:middle;cursor:pointer;background-image:none;border:1px solid transparent;border-radius:4px;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;-o-user-select:none;user-select:none}.btn:focus{outline:thin dotted;outline:5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;outline-offset:-2px}.btn:hover,.btn:focus{color:#333;text-decoration:none}.btn:active,.btn.active{background-image:none;outline:0;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.125);box-shadow:inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.125)}.btn.disabled,.btn[disabled],fieldset[disabled] .btn{pointer-events:none;cursor:not-allowed;opacity:.65;filter:alpha(opacity=65);-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none}.btn-default{color:#333;background-color:#fff;border-color:#ccc}.btn-default:hover,.btn-default:focus,.btn-default:active,.btn-default.active,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-default{color:#333;background-color:#ebebeb;border-color:#adadad}.btn-default:active,.btn-default.active,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-default{background-image:none}.btn-default.disabled,.btn-default[disabled],fieldset[disabled] .btn-default,.btn-default.disabled:hover,.btn-default[disabled]:hover,fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:hover,.btn-default.disabled:focus,.btn-default[disabled]:focus,fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:focus,.btn-default.disabled:active,.btn-default[disabled]:active,fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:active,.btn-default.disabled.active,.btn-default[disabled].active,fieldset[disabled] .btn-default.active{background-color:#fff;border-color:#ccc}.btn-default .badge{color:#fff;background-color:#fff}.btn-primary{color:#fff;background-color:#428bca;border-color:#357ebd}.btn-primary:hover,.btn-primary:focus,.btn-primary:active,.btn-primary.active,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary{color:#fff;background-color:#3276b1;border-color:#285e8e}.btn-primary:active,.btn-primary.active,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary{background-image:none}.btn-primary
```

Comment: This is only a 20% part of my file..

Comment: which editor do you use to open this file?

Comment: http://cssbeautify.com/ is your friend. This question should be closed since it is asking for a tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google CSS Beautifier, there are many good ones that work and can put it in a better format for you : ) I would link to one here but I'm not sure if that's allowed. Any of the top results from a google search should work fine, though.

Here is what the start of your code looks like after being run through one:

```
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary {
    display: block;
}

audio,canvas,video {
    display: inline-block;
}

audio:not([controls]) {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
}

[hidden],template {
    display: none;
}

html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

a {
    background: transparent;
}

a:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
}

a:active,a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}

h1 {
    margin: .67em 0;
    font-size: 2em;
}

abbr[title] {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

b,strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}

dfn {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

that can helps solve your problem :[css unpacker](http://cssunpacker.com/default.aspx)

```
    article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary
{
    display:block
}
    audio,canvas,video
{
    display:inline-block
}
    audio:not([controls])
{
    display:none;
    height:0
}
    [hidden],template
{
    display:none
}
    html
{
    font-family:sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust:100%
}
    body
{
    margin:0
}
    a
{
    background:transparent
}
    a:focus
{
    outline:thin dotted
}
    a:active,a:hover
{
    outline:0
}
    h1
{
    margin:.67em 0;
    font-size:2em
}
    abbr[title]
{
    border-bottom:1px dotted
}
    b,strong
{
    font-weight:bold
}
    dfn
{
    font-style:italic
}
    hr
{
    height:0;
    -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
    box-sizing:content-box
}
    mark
{
    color:#000;
    background:#ff0
}
    code,kbd,pre,samp
{
    font-family:monospace,serif;
    font-size:1em
}
    pre
{
    white-space:pre-wrap
}
    q
{
    quotes:"\201C" "\201D" "\2018" "\2019"
}
    small
{
    font-size:80%
}
    sub,sup
{
    position:relative;
    font-size:75%;
    line-height:0;
    vertical-align:baseline
}
    sup
{
    top:-0.5em
}
    sub
{
    bottom:-0.25em
}
    img
{
    border:0
}
    svg:not(:root)
{
    overflow:hidden
}
    figure
{
    margin:0
}
    fieldset
{
    padding:.35em .625em .75em;
    margin:0 2px;
    border:1px solid #c0c0c0
}
    legend
{
    padding:0;
    border:0
}
    button,input,select,textarea
{
    margin:0;
    font-family:inherit;
    font-size:100%
}
    button,input
{
    line-height:normal
}
    button,select
{
    text-transform:none
}
    button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]
{
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-appearance:button
}
    button[disabled],html input[disabled]
{
    cursor:default
}
    input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]
{
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box
}
    input[type="search"]
{
    -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
    box-sizing:content-box;
    -webkit-appearance:textfield
}
    input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration
{
    -webkit-appearance:none
}
    button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner
{
    padding:0;
    border:0
}
    textarea
{
    overflow:auto;
    vertical-align:top
}
    table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0
}
    @media print
{

{
    color:#000!important;
    text-shadow:none!important;
    background:transparent!important;
    box-shadow:none!important
}
    a,a:visited
{
    text-decoration:underline
}
    a[href]:after
{
    content:" (" attr(href) ")"
}
    abbr[title]:after
{
    content:" (" attr(title) ")"
}
    a[href^="javascript:"]:after,a[href^="#"]:after
{
    content:""
}
    pre,blockquote
{
    border:1px solid #999;
    page-break-inside:avoid
}
    thead
{
    display:table-header-group
}
    tr,img
{
    page-break-inside:avoid
}
    img
{
    max-width:100%!important
}
    @page
{
    margin:2cm .5cm
}
    p,h2,h3
{
    orphans:3;
    widows:3
}
    h2,h3
{
    page-break-after:avoid
}
    select
{
    background:#fff!important
}
.navbar
{
    display:none
}
.table td,.table th
{
    background-color:#fff!important
}
.btn>.caret,.dropup>.btn>.caret
{
    border-top-color:#000!important
}
.label
{
    border:1px solid #000
}
.table
{
    border-collapse:collapse!important
}
.table-bordered th,.table-bordered td
{
    border:1px solid #ddd!important
}

}
    ,:before,:after
{
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box
}
    html
{
    font-size:62.5%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)
}
    body
{
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:1.428571429;
    color:#333;
    background-color:#fff
}
    input,button,select,textarea
{
    font-family:inherit;
    font-size:inherit;
    line-height:inherit
}
    a
{
    color:#428bca;
    text-decoration:none
}
    a:hover,a:focus
{
    color:#2a6496;
    text-decoration:underline
}
    a:focus
{
    outline:thin dotted;
    outline:5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
    outline-offset:-2px
}
    img
{
    vertical-align:middle
}
.img-responsive
{
    display:block;
    height:auto;
    max-width:100%
}
.img-rounded
{
    border-radius:6px
}
.img-thumbnail
{
    display:inline-block;
    height:auto;
    max-width:100%;
    padding:4px;
    line-height:1.428571429;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .2s ease-in-out
}
.img-circle
{
    border-radius:50%
}
    hr
{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    border:0;
    border-top:1px solid #eee
}
.sr-only
{
    position:absolute;
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
    padding:0;
    margin:-1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    clip:rect(0,0,0,0);
    border:0
}
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,.h1,.h2,.h3,.h4,.h5,.h6
{
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight:500;
    line-height:1.1;
    color:inherit
}
    h1 small,h2 small,h3 small,h4 small,h5 small,h6 small,.h1 small,.h2 small,.h3 small,.h4 small,.h5 small,.h6 small,h1 .small,h2 .small,h3 .small,h4 .small,h5 .small,h6 .small,.h1 .small,.h2 .small,.h3 .small,.h4 .small,.h5 .small,.h6 .small
{
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:1;
    color:#999
}
    h1,h2,h3
{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:10px
}
    h1 small,h2 small,h3 small,h1 .small,h2 .small,h3 .small
{
    font-size:65%
}
    h4,h5,h6
{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px
}
    h4 small,h5 small,h6 small,h4 .small,h5 .small,h6 .small
{
    font-size:75%
}
    h1,.h1
{
    font-size:36px
}
    h2,.h2
{
    font-size:30px
}
    h3,.h3
{
    font-size:24px
}
    h4,.h4
{
    font-size:18px
}
    h5,.h5
{
    font-size:14px
}
    h6,.h6
{
    font-size:12px
}
    p
{
    margin:0 0 10px
}
.lead
{
    margin-bottom:20px;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:200;
    line-height:1.4
}
    @media(min-width:768px)
{
.lead
{
    font-size:21px
}

}
    small,.small
{
    font-size:85%
}
    cite
{
    font-style:normal
}
.text-muted
{
    color:#999
}
.text-primary
{
    color:#428bca
}
.text-primary:hover
{
    color:#3071a9
}
.text-warning
{
    color:#8a6d3b
}
.text-warning:hover
{
    color:#66512c
}
.text-danger
{
    color:#a94442
}
.text-danger:hover
{
    color:#843534
}
.text-success
{
    color:#3c763d
}
.text-success:hover
{
    color:#2b542c
}
.text-info
{
    color:#31708f
}
.text-info:hover
{
    color:#245269
}
.text-left
{
    text-align:left
}
.text-right
{
    text-align:right
}
.text-center
{
    text-align:center
}
.page-header
{
    padding-bottom:9px;
    margin:40px 0 20px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee
}
    ul,ol
{
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:10px
}
    ul ul,ol ul,ul ol,ol ol
{
    margin-bottom:0
}
.list-unstyled
{
    padding-left:0;
    list-style:none
}
.list-inline
{
    padding-left:0;
    list-style:none
}
.list-inline>li
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-left:5px
}
.list-inline>li:first-child
{
    padding-left:0
}
    dl
{
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:20px
}
    dt,dd
{
    line-height:1.428571429
}
    dt
{
    font-weight:bold
}
    dd
{
    margin-left:0
}
    @media(min-width:768px)
{
.dl-horizontal dt
{
    float:left;
    width:160px;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:left;
    text-align:right;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap
}
.dl-horizontal dd
{
    margin-left:180px
}
.dl-horizontal dd:before,.dl-horizontal dd:after
{
    display:table;
    content:" "
}
.dl-horizontal dd:after
{
    clear:both
}
.dl-horizontal dd:before,.dl-horizontal dd:after
{
    display:table;
    content:" "
}
.dl-horizontal dd:after
{
    clear:both
}

}
    abbr[title],abbr[data-original-title]
{
    cursor:help;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #999
}
.initialism
{
    font-size:90%;
    text-transform:uppercase
}
    blockquote
{
    padding:10px 20px;
    margin:0 0 20px;
    border-left:5px solid #eee
}
    blockquote p
{
    font-size:17.5px;
    font-weight:300;
    line-height:1.25
}
    blockquote p:last-child
{
    margin-bottom:0
}
    blockquote small,blockquote .small
{
    display:block;
    line-height:1.428571429;
    color:#999
}
    blockquote small:before,blockquote .small:before
{
    content:'\2014 \00A0'
}
    blockquote.pull-right
{
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-left:0;
    border-right:5px solid #eee;
    border-left:0
}
    blockquote.pull-right p,blockquote.pull-right small,blockquote.pull-right .small
{
    text-align:right
}
    blockquote.pull-right small:before,blockquote.pull-right .small:before
{
    content:''
}
    blockquote.pull-right small:after,blockquote.pull-right .small:after
{
    content:'\00A0 \2014'
}
    blockquote:before,blockquote:after
{
    content:""
}
    address
{
    margin-bottom:20px;
    font-style:normal;
    line-height:1.428571429
}
    code,kbd,pre,samp
{
    font-family:Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Courier New",monospace
}
    code
{
    padding:2px 4px;
    font-size:90%;
    color:#c7254e;
    white-space:nowrap;
    background-color:#f9f2f4;
    border-radius:4px
}
    pre
{
    display:block;
    padding:9.5px;
    margin:0 0 10px;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:1.428571429;
    color:#333;
    word-break:break-all;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius:4px
}
    pre code
{
    padding:0;
    font-size:inherit;
    color:inherit;
    white-space:pre-wrap;
    background-color:transparent;
    border-radius:0
}
.pre-scrollable
{
    max-height:340px;
    overflow-y:scroll
}
.container
{
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-left:15px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto
}
.container:before,.container:after
{
    display:table;
    content:" "
}
.container:after
{
    clear:both
}
.container:before,.container:after
{
    display:table;
    content:" "
}
.container:after
{
    clear:both
}
    @media(min-width:768px)
{
.container
{
    width:750px
}

}
    @media(min-width:992px)
{
.container
{
    width:970px
}

}
    @media(min-width:1200px)
{
.container
{
    width:1170px
}

}
.row
{
    margin-right:-15px;
    margin-left:-15px
}
.row:before,.row:after
{
    display:table;
    content:" "
}
.row:after
{
    clear:both
}
.row:before,.row:after
{
    display:table;
    content:" "
}
.row:after
{
    clear:both
}
.col-xs-1,.col-sm-1,.col-md-1,.col-lg-1,.col-xs-2,.col-sm-2,.col-md-2,.col-lg-2,.col-xs-3,.col-sm-3,.col-md-3,.col-lg-3,.col-xs-4,.col-sm-4,.col-md-4,.col-lg-4,.col-xs-5,.col-sm-5,.col-md-5,.col-lg-5,.col-xs-6,.col-sm-6,.col-md-6,.col-lg-6,.col-xs-7,.col-sm-7,.col-md-7,.col-lg-7,.col-xs-8,.col-sm-8,.col-md-8,.col-lg-8,.col-xs-9,.col-sm-9,.col-md-9,.col-lg-9,.col-xs-10,.col-sm-10,.col-md-10,.col-lg-10,.col-xs-11,.col-sm-11,.col-md-11,.col-lg-11,.col-xs-12,.col-sm-12,.col-md-12,.col-lg-12
{
    position:relative;
    min-height:1px;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-left:15px
}
.col-xs-1,.col-xs-2,.col-xs-3,.col-xs-4,.col-xs-5,.col-xs-6,.col-xs-7,.col-xs-8,.col-xs-9,.col-xs-10,.col-xs-11,.col-xs-12
{
    float:left
}
.col-xs-12
{
    width:100%
}
.col-xs-11
{
    width:91.66666666666666%
}
.col-xs-10
{
    width:83.33333333333334%
}
.col-xs-9
{
    width:75%
}
.col-xs-8
{
    width:66.66666666666666%
}
.col-xs-7
{
    width:58.333333333333336%
}
.col-xs-6
{
    width:50%
}
.col-xs-5
{
    width:41.66666666666667%
}
.col-xs-4
{
    width:33.33333333333333%
}
.col-xs-3
{
    width:25%
}
.col-xs-2
{
    width:16.666666666666664%
}
.col-xs-1
{
    width:8.333333333333332%
}
.col-xs-pull-12
{
    right:100%
}
.col-xs-pull-11
{
    right:91.66666666666666%
}
.col-xs-pull-10
{
    right:83.33333333333334%
}
.col-xs-pull-9
{
    right:75%
}
.col-xs-pull-8
{
    right:66.66666666666666%
}
.col-xs-pull-7
{
    right:58.333333333333336%
}
.col-xs-pull-6
{
    right:50%
}
.col-xs-pull-5
{
    right:41.66666666666667%
}
.col-xs-pull-4
{
    right:33.33333333333333%
}
.col-xs-pull-3
{
    right:25%
}
.col-xs-pull-2
{
    right:16.666666666666664%
}
.col-xs-pull-1
{
    right:8.333333333333332%
}
.col-xs-pull-0
{
    right:0
}
.col-xs-push-12
{
    left:100%
}
.col-xs-push-11
{
    left:91.66666666666666%
}
.col-xs-push-10
{
    left:83.33333333333334%
}
.col-xs-push-9
{
    left:75%
}
.col-xs-push-8
{
    left:66.66666666666666%
}
.col-xs-push-7
{
    left:58.333333333333336%
}
.col-xs-push-6
{
    left:50%
}
.col-xs-push-5
{
    left:41.66666666666667%
}
.col-xs-push-4
{
    left:33.33333333333333%
}
.col-xs-push-3
{
    left:25%
}
.col-xs-push-2
{
    left:16.666666666666664%
}
.col-xs-push-1
{
    left:8.333333333333332%
}
.col-xs-push-0
{
    left:0
}
.col-xs-offset-12
{
    margin-left:100%
}
.col-xs-offset-11
{
    margin-left:91.66666666666666%
}
.col-xs-offset-10
{
    margin-left:83.33333333333334%
}
.col-xs-offset-9
{
    margin-left:75%
}
.col-xs-offset-8
{
    margin-left:66.66666666666666%
}
.col-xs-offset-7
{
    margin-left:58.333333333333336%
}
.col-xs-offset-6
{
    margin-left:50%
}
.col-xs-offset-5
{
    margin-left:41.66666666666667%
}
.col-xs-offset-4
{
    margin-left:33.33333333333333%
}
.col-xs-offset-3
{
    margin-left:25%
}
.col-xs-offset-2
{
    margin-left:16.666666666666664%
}
.col-xs-offset-1
{
    margin-left:8.333333333333332%
}
.col-xs-offset-0
{
    margin-left:0
}
    @media(min-width:768px)
{
.col-sm-1,.col-sm-2,.col-sm-3,.col-sm-4,.col-sm-5,.col-sm-6,.col-sm-7,.col-sm-8,.col-sm-9,.col-sm-10,.col-sm-11,.col-sm-12
{
    float:left
}
.col-sm-12
{
    width:100%
}
.col-sm-11
{
    width:91.66666666666666%
}
.col-sm-10
{
    width:83.33333333333334%
}
.col-sm-9
{
    width:75%
}
.col-sm-8
{
    width:66.66666666666666%
}
.col-sm-7
{
    width:58.333333333333336%
}
.col-sm-6
{
    width:50%
}
.col-sm-5
{
    width:41.66666666666667%
}
.col-sm-4
{
    width:33.33333333333333%
}
.col-sm-3
{
    width:25%
}
.col-sm-2
{
    width:16.666666666666664%
}
.col-sm-1
{
    width:8.333333333333332%
}
.col-sm-pull-12
{
    right:100%
}
.col-sm-pull-11
{
    right:91.66666666666666%
}
.col-sm-pull-10
{
    right:83.33333333333334%
}
.col-sm-pull-9
{
    right:75%
}
.col-sm-pull-8
{
    right:66.66666666666666%
}
.col-sm-pull-7
{
    right:58.333333333333336%
}
.col-sm-pull-6
{
    right:50%
}
.col-sm-pull-5
{
    right:41.66666666666667%
}
.col-sm-pull-4
{
    right:33.33333333333333%
}
.col-sm-pull-3
{
    right:25%
}
.col-sm-pull-2
{
    right:16.666666666666664%
}
.col-sm-pull-1
{
    right:8.333333333333332%
}
.col-sm-pull-0
{
    right:0
}
.col-sm-push-12
{
    left:100%
}
.col-sm-push-11
{
    left:91.66666666666666%
}
.col-sm-push-10
{
    left:83.33333333333334%
}
.col-sm-push-9
{
    left:75%
}
.col-sm-push-8
{
    left:66.66666666666666%
}
.col-sm-push-7
{
    left:58.333333333333336%
}
.col-sm-push-6
{
    left:50%
}
.col-sm-push-5
{
    left:41.66666666666667%
}
.col-sm-push-4
{
    left:33.33333333333333%
}
.col-sm-push-3
{
    left:25%
}
.col-sm-push-2
{
    left:16.666666666666664%
}
.col-sm-push-1
{
    left:8.333333333333332%
}
.col-sm-push-0
{
    left:0
}
.col-sm-offset-12
{
    margin-left:100%
}
.col-sm-offset-11
{
    margin-left:91.66666666666666%
}
.col-sm-offset-10
{
    margin-left:83.33333333333334%
}
.col-sm-offset-9
{
    margin-left:75%
}
.col-sm-offset-8
{
    margin-left:66.66666666666666%
}
.col-sm-offset-7
{
    margin-left:58.333333333333336%
}
.col-sm-offset-6
{
    margin-left:50%
}
.col-sm-offset-5
{
    margin-left:41.66666666666667%
}
.col-sm-offset-4
{
    margin-left:33.33333333333333%
}
.col-sm-offset-3
{
    margin-left:25%
}
.col-sm-offset-2
{
    margin-left:16.666666666666664%
}
.col-sm-offset-1
{
    margin-left:8.333333333333332%
}
.col-sm-offset-0
{
    margin-left:0
}

}
    @media(min-width:992px)
{
.col-md-1,.col-md-2,.col-md-3,.col-md-4,.col-md-5,.col-md-6,.col-md-7,.col-md-8,.col-md-9,.col-md-10,.col-md-11,.col-md-12
{
    float:left
}
.col-md-12
{
    width:100%
}
.col-md-11
{
    width:91.66666666666666%
}
.col-md-10
{
    width:83.33333333333334%
}
.col-md-9
{
    width:75%
}
.col-md-8
{
    width:66.66666666666666%
}
.col-md-7
{
    width:58.333333333333336%
}
.col-md-6
{
    width:50%
}
.col-md-5
{
    width:41.66666666666667%
}
.col-md-4
{
    width:33.33333333333333%
}
.col-md-3
{
    width:25%
}
.col-md-2
{
    width:16.666666666666664%
}
.col-md-1
{
    width:8.333333333333332%
}
.col-md-pull-12
{
    right:100%
}
.col-md-pull-11
{
    right:91.66666666666666%
}
.col-md-pull-10
{
    right:83.33333333333334%
}
.col-md-pull-9
{
    right:75%
}
.col-md-pull-8
{
    right:66.66666666666666%
}
.col-md-pull-7
{
    right:58.333333333333336%
}
.col-md-pull-6
{
    right:50%
}
.col-md-pull-5
{
    right:41.66666666666667%
}
.col-md-pull-4
{
    right:33.33333333333333%
}
.col-md-pull-3
{
    right:25%
}
.col-md-pull-2
{
    right:16.666666666666664%
}
.col-md-pull-1
{
    right:8.333333333333332%
}
.col-md-pull-0
{
    right:0
}
.col-md-push-12
{
    left:100%
}
.col-md-push-11
{
    left:91.66666666666666%
}
.col-md-push-10
{
    left:83.33333333333334%
}
.col-md-push-9
{
    left:75%
}
.col-md-push-8
{
    left:66.66666666666666%
}
.col-md-push-7
{
    left:58.333333333333336%
}
.col-md-push-6
{
    left:50%
}
.col-md-push-5
{
    left:41.66666666666667%
}
.col-md-push-4
{
    left:33.33333333333333%
}
.col-md-push-3
{
    left:25%
}
.col-md-push-2
{
    left:16.666666666666664%
}
.col-md-push-1
{
    left:8.333333333333332%
}
.col-md-push-0
{
    left:0
}
.col-md-offset-12
{
    margin-left:100%
}
.col-md-offset-11
{
    margin-left:91.66666666666666%
}
.col-md-offset-10
{
    margin-left:83.33333333333334%
}
.col-md-offset-9
{
    margin-left:75%
}
.col-md-offset-8
{
    margin-left:66.66666666666666%
}
.col-md-offset-7
{
    margin-left:58.333333333333336%
}
.col-md-offset-6
{
    margin-left:50%
}
.col-md-offset-5
{
    margin-left:41.66666666666667%
}
.col-md-offset-4
{
    margin-left:33.33333333333333%
}
.col-md-offset-3
{
    margin-left:25%
}
.col-md-offset-2
{
    margin-left:16.666666666666664%
}
.col-md-offset-1
{
    margin-left:8.333333333333332%
}
.col-md-offset-0
{
    margin-left:0
}

}
    @media(min-width:1200px)
{
```

Answer (score 1):

Use http://jsbeautifier.org/ to get an indented code.

It can work with HTML, JavaScript and CSS.